# Replacing a specific word in an h2 element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple `h2` element that looks like this:

```
<h2>New Agent - Record Status:  
  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RecordDisplayStatus)                                         
</h2>
```

When a user clicks a button I need to be able to change the word `Agent` in there to `Agency`. This was my first attempt but I keep getting the following message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'
```

Here's my first hack at it

```
$('.head h2').replace("Agent", "Agency");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are trying to call `replace` on a jQuery object. You need to call `replace` on a string, so try this:

```
    var newval = $('.head h2').text().replace("Agent", "Agency");
    $('.head h2').text(newval);
```

And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/7Y8DF/)